# yii2 switch button that render page with pjax

Tags: yii2, pjax, yii2-model

I'm trying to make a form that changes the input according to the button pressed, using pjax of yii2, no page loads.

**My view**

```html
<div id="container-ajax">
           
                 <?php Pjax::begin([]);  
                  echo $this->render('noleggia_andata', ['form' => $form, 'noleggi_partenza' => $noleggi_partenza]);

                Pjax::end(); ?>
             </div>
```

This is one, I tried with ActionView from Button but do not know how to do, can you give me any suggestions?
**View**

```html
<?= Html::a("Go", ['noleggi/noleggia_andata'], ['class' => 'btn-discard-orange']) */ ?>
```

**Controller**

```html
 public function actionNoleggia_andata()
    {

    $noleggi_partenza = new Noleggi_partenza;

   return $this->render('noleggia_andata',['noleggi_partenza' => $noleggi_partenza]);
    }
```

**Controller view rederAjax**

public function actionNoleggia_andata()
    {

```
 $noleggi_partenza = new Noleggi_partenza;
```

return $this->renderAjax('noleggia_andata',['noleggi_partenza' => $noleggi_partenza]);
    }

[image]

Comment: Any suggestions or advice for the way forward?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a little confused with your question. Can you provide more details?

Comment: try this http://blog.neattutorials.com/examples/pjax/web/site/auto-refresh

Comment: In view "noleggi" there is a form I created but parts of the form change depending on the button pressed, i tried doing renderAjax  
but it does not read well the model,the two forms are not communicate.